# Distance based Spatial sampling

Tags: sampling, spatial, distance

I am struggling with spatial sampling of data which has Latitude & Longitude for data points. I need to do sampling such that no adjacent or nearby point should get  selected ( Need to give some radius criteria)in a sampled dataset. Kindly help.

Basically my problem statement is my sampled data set should have points which are 200 meters (or x meters) far away from each other.

Comment: Instead of throwing away data, consider adopting statistical procedures that are appropriate for your data, your model, and your problem.  Could you tell us more about those things?

Answer (score 0):

You can build up your sample iteratively:

Start with a copy of your full dataset $S$.

1. Pick a single observation $i$ at random from $S$.
2. Compute the distances of all points in $i$ to $S$.
3. Remove all observations from $S$ that are too close to $i$ (as well as $i$ itself).
4. Repeat until you have a large enough sample or $S$ is empty.

A few things to note:

- Not every observation has the same probability of being selected. Intuitively, observations in clusters are less likely to be selected as they compete with each other. Observations at the *centre* of a cluster are particularly unlikely to be selected.
- It is not guaranteed that you will be able to get a sample of your desired size using this method. In case you run out of observations before reaching your desired sample size, you would need to repeat the whole procedure until you get lucky.

Comment: Unfortunately, even repeating the procedure does not fix the problem of unequal selection probabilities.  It's even worse than that, because the selection of one point can be strongly correlated with the selection of other points, even those far away.  The question as asked doesn't offer enough information to enable one to offer a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

@mrischard.
I solved this problem by multiplying LAT with LONG and sorted the data in ascending order (Similar LAT & LONG produces almost similar product when geographical area is of city size). After sorting , I will apply batching i.e. 1,2,3,4,5,6,.... , 10 And this will give me 10 samples in which points are 10 nearest point distant.